# Запятая после "и еще"

Tags: запятые

Скажите, нужна ли запятая после "и еще". Сначала идет длинная речь о достижениях университета, а потом предложение:

*И еще, 50 лет назад университет впервые открыл двери для вас!*

Спасибо!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102388/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если так уместно сказать, то запятая нужна. А возможно, просто неверно использовать "и ещё" в качестве вводного слова и надо перефразировать:

> *Кроме того, 50 лет назад университет впервые открыл двери для вас!*

Я, когда хочу сказать подобным образом, просто избегаю таких слов, как у вас, которые за вводные обычно не считаются, а вообще вопрос интересный.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Это речь одного из наших лекторов. И слов из нее не выкинешь((( и не заменишь, к сжалению

Comment: У вас в первом абзаце 2 пунктуационные ошибки. Но второе предложение лучше перефразировать. Вы же здесь как корректор, поэтому говорю.

Comment: @oleedd *Вы же здесь как корректор.* Ну, это я сам, добровольно. Какие ошибки-то? Первая не ошибка, а опечатка.

Comment: Стоп. А чего опечатки не ошибки? *Возможно использовать* - ну какое здесь вводное? И кажется, что "а вообще" вводное, там явная пауза.

Comment: Нет, "вообще" не вводное: здесь не "вообще говоря", а "в целом", "в принципе". Не "возможно использовать", а "может быть + сама мысль".

Comment: Ну тогда союз "а" мешает. С ним предложения совсем по-другому воспринимается. Тогда там нет никакого противопоставления.

Comment: @oleedd: в каком случае нет противопоставления? Без него, как у меня? Да, с А лучше, спасибо.

Comment: Не то имею в виду. "а надо" — здесь А как-то не в тему.

Comment: Ну да, не совсем удачно получилось. У меня вышло противопоставление отрицанию "неверно", но на самом деле да: если бы раздельно писалось и смысл был соответствующий, тогда бы оно имело место, а так нет.

Comment: Вот-вот. И я об этом. Именно поэтому подумал, что слово "возможно" как-то этому способствует, и понял структуру предложения совсем иначе.

Answer (score 2):

Если "и ещё" рассматривать как вводное сочетание (то есть если с его помощью автор просто выделяет, подчёркивает важность далее идущего сообщения), то тогда можно оформить с постановкой запятой:

1. > Бла-бла-бла. И ещё, 50 лет назад университет впервые открыл двери для
   >   вас!

Или даже с тире (что допустимо)

2. > Бла-бла-бла. И ещё — 50 лет назад университет впервые открыл двери для
   >   вас!

---

Более того, если "реконструировать" предложение в бессоюзное сложное...

> Бла-бла-бла. И ещё хочу сказать: 50 лет назад университет впервые открыл двери для вас!

...и затем "выбросить" предикативную основу, то получится так, с двоеточием:

3. > И ещё: 50 лет назад университет впервые открыл двери для вас!

Это в таком случае можно или вводным осознавать, или — если хочется — просто обрезком полного предложения с удалённым, но домысливаемым сказуемым "хочу сказать".

В корпусе есть примеры и с запятой при *"и ещё"*, и с двоеточием, и с тире.

***Ответ***: Вы можете использовать после "и ещё" и запятую, и двоеточие, и тире. Обособлять нужно. Но только в том случае, если "и ещё" не часть описываемой ситуации, а ВАША оценка ситуации, ваша внутренняя рефлексия относительно описываемой ситуации, ваше вставное лексическое субъективное добавление в предложение, цель которого — выделить высказывание, часть высказывания, подчеркнуть его значимость.

Comment: А что говорят словари вводных слов? Есть там такое?

Comment: Я не видел, чтобы где-то в лексикографии было отрефлексировано "и ещё" в качестве вводного слова.  Но не всё есть в словарях. А раз так, то нужно самим думать, аналогии использовать. Определять его вводность по сопоставлению с семантически схожими "отрефлексированными" вводными.  Всё-таки в корпусе куча есть примеров, где обособленное "и ещё" ну явно как вводное ощущается. Кроме того, я же написал, что "и ещё" можно осознавать и как второстепенный член неполного предложения с опущенным сказуемым.

Comment: Отрефлексировано — это вообще о чём?!

Comment: Ну, осмыслено, обмозговано, проанализировано.

Answer (score 2):

***И еще*** (= это важно отметить), 50 лет назад университет впервые открыл двери для Вас!

1) Разумеется, запятая нужна. Можно именовать оборот любым способом, но он **не встраивается** в это предложение никаким образом.

Но иногда оборот **вписывается в предложение** и не обособляется: ***И еще*** я не знал ни слова по-английски, но надо было общаться, и я довольно быстро начал говорить.

2) Оборот чисто разговорный, не очень подходит по стилю для торжественной речи. Значение примерно такое: и вот что еще можно сказать/добавить. Для обособления можно использовать разные знаки (запятая, тире, двоеточие, точка), что зависит от структуры предложения и от стиля.

3) В книжной литературе подобные обороты используется в речи персонажей: ***И еще вот***, очень важное: на обратном пути Алеша рассказывал.. [Михаил Шишкин.2005]

*Биографические журналистские раскопки и скандальные «признания» начались уже года через два или три после выхода книги. **И еще**. Эта книга написана человеком двадцати трех лет.*